# How to turn a CSS value unique (not shared with any other html sections)

Tags: html, css, syntax

I have a bunch of icons (font awesome) spread all over my website. I know how to change their colours using CSS, but the problem is that it's changes them all.

For example, I need the footer ones to be white (check image below), while others in other site sections remain with the original colours.

How can I do this?

[image: Footer Icons]

**MY HTML FOOTER**

```
<footer id="footer">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <ul class="icons social">
                                <li><a href="#" class="icon alt fa-linkedin fa-2x"><span class="label">Linkedin</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="icon alt fa-twitter fa-2x"><span class="label">Twitter</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="icon alt fa-facebook fa-2x"><span class="label">Facebook</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="icon alt fa-youtube fa-2x"><span class="label">YouTube</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="icon alt fa-flickr fa-2x"><span class="label">Flickr</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <p class="copyright">&copy; STOPTRANS INTERNACIONAL II - 2017 All Rights Reserved.</p>
                    </footer>
```

**MY ICONS CSS SECTION**

```
/* Icon */

    .icon {
        text-decoration: none;
        border-bottom: none;
        position: relative;
    }

        .icon:before {
            -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            font-family: FontAwesome;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
            text-transform: none !important;
        }

        .icon > .label {
            display: none;
        }

        .icon:before {
            cursor: inherit;
        }

    .icon-wrapper {
        width: 4em;
        height: 2em;
        line-height: 2em;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        margin: 1.235em 0;
    }

        .icon-wrapper:before, .icon-wrapper:after {
            content: '';
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            border-left: solid 2em transparent;
            border-right: solid 2em transparent;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
        }

        .icon-wrapper:before {
            border-bottom: solid 1.235em;
            top: -1.235em;
        }

        .icon-wrapper:after {
            border-top: solid 1.235em;
            bottom: -1.235em;
        }

        .icon-wrapper .icon {
            cursor: default;
        }

            .icon-wrapper .icon:before {
                font-size: 2rem;
            }

        .icon-wrapper.major {
            display: block;
            margin: 1.235em 0 3.235em 0;
        }

        .icon-wrapper.small {
            font-size: 0.75em;
        }

            .icon-wrapper.small .icon:before {
                font-size: 1.25rem;
            }

    .icon-wrapper {
        background-color: #f6f6f6;
        box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 0 #f6f6f6, 0 1px 0 0 #f6f6f6;
    }

        .icon-wrapper:before {
            border-bottom-color: #f6f6f6;
        }

        .icon-wrapper:after {
            border-top-color: #f6f6f6;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `#footer .icon {color:white}`

Comment: Worked perfect, what about the hover color, only for the footer? And if I want different hover colours for each icon?

Comment: The same would apply for the hover, just take your existing rule, copy it,  and prefix it with `#footer `. If you want different hover colors for each then you'd have to either use IDs, classes, or pseudo-classes like `:nth-child()` to select them. In my answer above, you're increasing the specificity of your CSS selector rule so that it overrides the other rules you have set. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 0):

For the hover color change I used:

```
#footer .icon:hover {color:#A6A6A6}
```